# A better way to remove an item the index is unknown from the array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

I have an array that has zeroes in random indexes. The indexes for given different arrays are unknown. I used the following for loop to find and remove the zeros, so the resulting array is the same one without the zeros.

```
for (let i=0; i< arr.length; i++){
    if(arr[i] === 0){
      itemIndex = arr.indexOf(arr[i]);
      arr.splice(itemIndex, 1); //removes the zero at the index
      i = 0; //resets the i to zero so that every item in the array is searched even after it is altered.
    }
  }
```

As you can see, it resets the "i" to zero so that I can iterate through the array again because it will be altered and indexes of the zeroes will change. I am wondering if there is a better way to do this? I have a feeling that this could be coded better.

Comment: Array.filter()...

Comment: Go backwards...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to decrement `i` by 1. Also, there is no need to use `indexOf` when you already have the index.

```
for (let i=0; i< arr.length; i++){
    if(arr[i] === 0){
      arr.splice(i, 1); //removes the zero at the index
      i--;
    }
  }
```

Looping backwards also solves the issue without additional counter manipulation, as only elements that have already been checked will be shifted.

Of course, it is much easier to use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) instead.

```
arr = arr.filter(x => x !== 0);
```

Comment: the filter wouldn't have the random aspect of the code they are trying to implement.

Comment: oh nvm I read the problem domain wrong. you nailed it lol

Answer (score 2):

Here's a couple options you can take here...

1. Retain your for loop: instead of `i = 0`, you could decrement `i` instead (i.e. replace `i = 0` with `i--`)
2. Replace the loop with a filter: `arr = arr.filter(element => element !== 0)`

Both will modify the array in place, like you wanted. The second option will not work if `arr` was initialized as a constant. If that's the case, you'll have to go with option 1, or assign the filter result to a new array and use that after the filter in place of your original array.

Second option is a bit cleaner, but the first is a small change to your existing code to have it to work as you expected.

Answer (score 1):

You could count *down* (i.e. `for (let i=arr.length-1; i>=0; i--)` so the indices of the elements you haven't checked yet won't change.

Answer (score 1):

```
let result = arr.filter(e => e!==0)
```

Or if you want to stick with the for loop implementation :

what about populating a new array instead of mutating the one you are looping over:

```
let result = []

for(let e of arr) {
    if(e!==0) result.push(e)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my preferred method of removing items from an array like this.

```js
const newArray = array.filter(item => ele !== 0)
```